# Facing issues while trying to init Bubblewrap for TWA installation

Tags: trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

I am new to Bubblewrap. I downloaded Node.js and then did `npm i -g @bubblewrap/cli`. It threw some warnings, but it did finish.

After this, when I am doing `bubblewrap init --manifest https://beegle.app/bpro-manifest.json`, I am getting some errors which I don't understand and don't know how to solve.

Here are the error messages:

```
[Mukeshs-MacBook-Air:beeglepro-bubblewrap mghatiya$ bubblewrap init --manifest https://beegle.app/bpro-manifest.json
internal/util.js:206
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:206:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mghatiya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/@bubblewrap/cli/node_modules/get-stream/index.js:7:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mghatiya/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/@bubblewrap/cli/node_modules/fetch-h2/dist/lib/body.js:6:22)
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I had old version of Node.js installed and for whatever reason, even though I had just downloaded Node.js from the website, the latest one was not loaded or it was not loaded at the correct place or whatever.

So basically warnings thrown by `npm i -g @bubblewrap/cli` were indeed strong ones and it had not completed its job.

I upgraded to the latest Node.js version with `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node` and now the errors that I posted have gone in the `bubblewrap init` action.

Of course, as is the case with all development things, now I face the new errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Windows with npm in version 8.16.2 (nvm). Thanks @mukesh for pointing that point. Following `nvm list` and `nvm use 14.18.0`, I reinstalled bubblewrap and the `bubblewrap init` command worked this time.