# bubblewrap init throws -bash: bubblewrap: command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

I am building a PWA and following [this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/app-store-pwa/bubblewrap) to create a TWA. `npm i -g @bubblewrap/cli` runs fine. When I run

```
bubblewrap init --manifest=http://localhost:8000/static/manifest.webmanifest
```

or

```
bubblewrap init --manifest="http://localhost:8000/static/manifest.webmanifest"
```

or

```
bubblewrap init --manifest="<http://localhost:8000/static/manifest.webmanifest>"
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: bubblewrap: command not found
```

I have updated npm and bubblewrap based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428044/facing-issues-while-trying-to-init-bubblewrap-for-twa-installation) and am still getting the error. My index.html is inside the `static` directory.

- node v17.6.0
- npm v8.5.1
- java v17
- jdk v11

Does anyone have advice on why bubblewrap isn't being recognized?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. in my case the issue was that when i installed the bubblewrap with npm, it installed it in the v18.12.1 location, but my npm was using another version (in this case v16.16.0). so using the `bubblewrap` command resulted in the same error as you mentioned.
I stumbled upon this question that solved my problem: [NVM: npm install -g keeps using wrong version of node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022173/nvm-npm-install-g-keeps-using-wrong-version-of-node)

So basically on Ubuntu `npm` install packages globally using `prefix` variable that is set in a file called `~/.npmrc`. I fixed it with editing `~/.npmrc` file, and made sure that `prefix` points to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

i use `npx bubblewrap init --manifest=https://my-website/manifest.json` in VSC and it worked (windows10)